# how to start Rails 2 app (Ruby 1.8.3, Rails 2.3.8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am having one file intello erp,ruby version is 1.8.3 and rails 2.3.8 When I said rails s
why it is not starting server?it is showing given below.help me

```
exists  
          exists  app/controllers
          exists  app/helpers
          exists  app/models
          exists  app/views/layouts
          exists  config/environments
          exists  config/initializers
          exists  config/locales
          exists  db
          exists  doc
          exists  lib
          exists  lib/tasks
          exists  log
          exists  public/images
          exists  public/javascripts
          exists  public/stylesheets
          exists  script/performance
```

Comment: you better find a tutorial how to install rvm, ruby 2.0 and rails 4 and do not waste time to start a rails 2 project

Comment: but how can I run this file?

Comment: as I remember it's `./script/server start`

Comment: using ruby script/server command I started the server but again it is showing 
Sorry. Something Went Wrong.
Error 500- Internal Server Error
Go to home
Previous page

Comment: Is anybody can tell what i have to change in database.yml file how to resolve this problem?

Comment: nobody can tell you anything without you posting the server logs and the needed files.. there is no magician here to guess where your problem is.

Comment: In databas.yml you have to define mysql user, password and databse name. Better you go through this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/ and then try to create application

Answer (score 5):

try this `ruby script/server` from your root directory this will start your server

Answer (score 3):

If You are in root folder of the project run:

```
ruby script/server
```

Comment: I am in root directory only. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Get into the root directory:

```
cd ~/Directory
```

Then type the following in console to run the server script:

```
ruby script/server
```

Should then be supplied the following information:

```
[2015-12-15 10:41:52] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-12-15 10:41:52] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]
[2015-12-15 10:41:52] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4436 port=3000
```

You should then be available to access your local site:http://localhost:3000/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `ruby script/server` from root directory of project. This is because you are using Rails version 2.X.X. If you use Rails 3.X.X then you can run `rails s` or `rails server` to run Webrick Service to run your application. After doing this, use `http://localhost:3000` from your browser. You will get your application.

Answer (score 0):

Then type the following in console to run the server script from inside your project:

```
 cd script 
 chmod u+x server
```

Then,

```
 exec script/server or ./script server
```